# how can i update the div data with xml http request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, xmlhttprequest

On my JSP page, I need to get the data from the XML HTTP request,

here is my code,,

```
<body>
<div id="ptab">
  <button onclick="next()"></button>
</div>

<script>
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","url",false);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
 document.getElementById("ptab").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
</script>


<script>
function next(){
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("ptab").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", 'url?id=2', true);
  xhttp.send();
}

</script>

</body>
```

when I click the button, it displays the data getting from the URL but it didn't update the URL with id '2'.

firstly, when the page loads, I have to display the data from the URL.
when I click the button, I need to display the data from URL?id='2'

how can I get this,

or any other approaches to fetch the response without refreshing the page

Comment: Seems like what you are doing should work. Only issue I see is you replace the div with the button that has the next() call in it

Comment: @epascarello the page blinks the data of url?id='2', and automatically changes to data of url. Maybe the "url" xmlhttp request calls when page load,.. any approach to call xmlhttp request call once only when page loads at beginning of tab open

Comment: Well you have a button that acts like a submit button so that will submit the form if it is in one. `<button type="button">` set it to a button type so it does not submit